# raspberry pi3 bluetoothctl scan on command

Tags: java, bluetooth, raspberry-pi3

I use raspberry pi 3.
Type 'bluetoothctl' in the linux command shell and type 'scan on', then
Raspberry pi search nearby devices.
i want to be able to search for devices on one command line.
for example, bluetoothctl + scan on , but i can't find this command
i tried `bluetoothctl` && `scan on(X)<br>bluetoothctl --agent` 
`scan on (X)<br>bluetoothctl ;` 
`scan on(X)`
but these do not work.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
bluetoothctl -- scan on
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make one python script for execute command 
import os;

os.system("")